# Using Y_True as an input to intermediate layer

Tags: neural-network, keras, lstm, keras-layer, loss-function

I am trying to implement a structure that looks like the following block diagram. I have the ability to implement it from scratch but when I want to implement it in Keras I have some difficulties. Any help would be appreciated. Specifically I have two questions about its implementation in Keras.

1) How can I have my actual output as a separate input layer as it is shown in the following block diagram. As each input is fed into the network, I want the corresponding gold standard output in the Y_true section that I showed in the diagram.
2) If I want to back propagate the cost function from cost section, is it possible to just go backward from the vertical path and not the path that has the copy of the third layer.

[image: Overall block diagram of the Keras]

Comment: Are you sure you don't want just a custom loss function? I mean, Y_true and 3rd layer are exactly what goes inside a loss function, no need to create any different model for that.

Comment: Yes Daniel, I am sure :-)  My cost evaluation has two steps. Once I compute an scalar that I need and then I use it for computation inside my cost function. The problems is, if I want to use it inside my cost function block, then I have to make an if clause inside my cost function which Keras hates because it is a graph computation.

Comment: You'll have to make the if clause inside your custom layer anyway, no?

Comment: There are a few "if" computations that keras likes in the [Backend](https://keras.io/backend/), such as `equal`, `not_equal`, `greater`, `less` and others. If you keep everything as tensors, it will probably be ok.

Comment: I don't do if clause inside that computation section because I multiply my intermediate layers with each other which basically does the task. However it is not possible to do so inside the cost function. Because cost function does not have access to the variables that I want to make that computation.

Comment: If you post the computation you want to do, I might help you creating the loss functoin. It does have access to external vars, but you must use everything as tensors.

Comment: The main difficulty in your graph is the "scalar" going into the loss function. Keras will demand that you know that scalar as part of Y_true. If you know it, then it may be possible to do that.

Comment: Thanks Dan, Here is a link to the problem that I wrote down. Let me know if you have more questions.https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0c-5LPY0RKWZkdLRXNWbW1SUmVJWVkzRFN6XzNLdm5pX2tN/view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147969/discussion-between-daniel-and-rzk).

Comment: So.... Do you mean, only one scalar for the entire batch? Or one scalar for each sample in the batch? --- In other words: in your picture, the lists you showed are the entire batch (with 3 samples)? Or are they just one sample with shape (3,3)? -- The output of your model is (None,3) or (None,3,3)?

Comment: That's just one sample. Each sample is a sequence actually. So, each sample is of length 5 in my case that each of the five points can have one of the three possible classes.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this. The main idea is you create a model with 2 outputs, one for the y_pred and one for the loss. When compiling that model, use a list of loss functions and we just care about the second loss

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Input
from keras.layers.merge import _Merge
from keras import backend as K
import numpy as np

class CustomMerge(_Merge):
    def _merge_function(self, inputs):
        output = inputs[0]
        for i in range(1, len(inputs)):
            output += inputs[i]
        return output

class CustomLoss(_Merge):

    def _merge_function(self, inputs):
        output = inputs[0]
        for i in range(1, len(inputs)):
            output -= inputs[i]
        return output


input = Input(name= 'input', shape=[100])
y_true = Input(name = 'y_true', shape=[1])
layer1 = Dense(1024)(input)
layer2 = Dense(128)(layer1)
layer3 = Dense(1)(layer2)

y_pred = CustomMerge()([layer3, y_true]) # do whatever you want to calculate y_pred
loss = CustomLoss()([layer3, y_pred]) # do whatever you want to calculate loss

model = Model(inputs=[input, y_true], outputs = [y_pred, loss])
losses = [
            lambda y_true, y_pred: K.zeros([1]),  # don't care about this loss
            lambda y_true, y_pred: K.mean(K.square(y_pred), axis=-1),  # we only care about this loss and just care about y_pred, no matter what the y_true is.
        ]
model.compile(loss=losses, optimizer='adam')
model.summary()

batch_size = 32

X, Y = get_batch(batch_size)
L = np.zeros(batch_size)

model.train_on_batch([X, Y], [Y, L])
```

Comment: Thanks An. It seems like a solution but I have a question, it's nice that there are two types of loss inside losses. How can I make sure which one is used? This is pretty much what I am looking for if I could know how can the network know which loss to use.

Comment: The model has two outputs, each loss will apply to each output. So, the first loss goes with `y_pred` and the second loss goes with `loss`.

Answer (score 1):

I experimented on a custom loss function, it's possible, but it's a little more complicated than usual (and I have no idea if training will succeed...):

```
import keras.backend as K

def customLoss(yTrue,yPred): 

    #starting with tensors shaped like (batch,5,3)

    #let's find the predicted class to compare - this example works with categorical classification (only one true class per element in a sequence)   
    trueMax = K.argmax(yTrue,axis=-1)
    predMax = K.argmax(yPred,axis=-1)
                #at this point, shapes become (batch,5)

    #let's find the different results:
    neq = K.not_equal(trueMax,predMax)

    #now we sum the different results. The ones with sum=0 are true
    neqsum = K.sum(neq,axis=-1)
                #shape now is only (batch)

    #to avoid false values being greater than 1, we do another comparison:
    trueFalse = K.equal(neqsum,0)

    #we adjust from values between 0 and 1 to values between -1 and 1:
    adj = (2*trueFalse) - 1

    #now it's time to create Loss1 and Loss2 (which I don't know)   
    #they are different from regular losses, because you must keep the batch size so you can multiply the result with "adj":

    l1 = someLoss keeping batch size   
    l2 = someLoss keeping batch size
              #these two must be shaped also like (batch)

    #then apply your formula:
    res = ((1-adj)*l1 + ((adj-1)*l2)
               #this step could perhaps be replaced by the K.switch function    
               #it would be probably much more efficient, but I'd have to learn how to use it first   

    #and finally, sum over the batch dimension, or use a mean value or anything similar
    return K.sum(res) #or K.mean(res)
```

A test (shapes are a little different, but keep the same number of dimensions):

```
def tprint(t):
    print(K.shape(t).eval())
    print(t.eval())
    print("\n")

x = np.array([[[.2,.7,.1],[.6,.3,.1],[.3,.3,.4],[.6,.3,.1],[.3,.6,.1]],[[.5,.2,.3],[.3,.6,.1],[.2,.7,.1],[.7,.15,.15],[.5,.2,.3]]])
y = np.array([[[0.,1.,0.],[1.,0.,0.],[0.,0.,1.],[1.,0.,0.],[0.,1.,0.]],[[0.,1.,0.],[0.,0.,1.],[0.,1.,0.],[1.,00.,00.],[1.,0.,0.]]])


x = K.variable(x)
y = K.variable(y)

xM = K.argmax(x,axis=-1)
yM = K.argmax(y,axis=-1)

neq = K.not_equal(xM,yM)

neqsum = K.sum(neq,axis=-1,keepdims=False)
trueFalse = K.equal(neqsum,0)
adj = (2*trueFalse) - 1

l1 = 3 * K.sum(K.sum(y,axis=-1),axis=-1)
l2 = 7 * K.sum(K.sum(y,axis=-1),axis=-1)

res = ((1-adj)*l1) +((adj-1)*l2)
sumres = K.sum(res) #or K.mean, or something similar
tprint(xM)
tprint(yM)
tprint(neq)
tprint(neqsum)
tprint(trueFalse)
tprint(adj)
tprint(l1)
tprint(l2)
tprint(res)
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Can you please explain how can I connect this to the diagram that I showed above?

Comment: You don't need the diagram, use it as a custom loss function: `model.compile(loss=customLoss, optimizer=<chooseAnOptimizer>)`

Comment: Thanks Dan, the thing is I need one extra variable inside my custom cost function. How can I specify that extra variable.

Comment: With `K.variable(some numpy array)`. Inside loss functions, you should do everything with backend functions, to keep it as a graph.

Comment: This variable is changing on each instance of reading but custom loss functions accepts two argument. Even if you pass a variable to the custom loss function, custom loss function is going to be initialized once during the model set up and after that it'll continue use that.

Comment: What is an " instance of reading"? How do you calculate that var?

Comment: Can you apply the solution in my answer?